# Как лучше защищать админку? Как лучше реализовать админку?

Tags: php, cms, mvc, mysql

1. Как лучше защищать админку? Если перейти на **site.ru/admin/editNews**, то:
2. пользователь переходит на данную страницу;
3. по сессии определяется, тот ли это человек, который залогинился под админкой;
4. грузим под него страницу с новостями и с инструментами для редактирования.
      Безопасно ли так?
5. Как лучше реализовать админку?
6. Всё перенаправляем на **index.php**, далее на **Router.php** (как в паттерне mvc).
7. А далее в **Router.php** определяем, что загрузить и отобразить на экране.
8. Допустим, страницу **editNews.php** или **ListNews.php** для просмотра.

Или же вы посоветуете что-либо полегче. Спасибо.

Comment: Поправочка: Router.php  никакого отношения к MVC не имеет. Это паттерн Front Controller pattern (единая точка входа).

Answer (score 0):

1-4 - нет, не безопасно. Пользователь может загрузить страницу в iframe и не знать об этом. Нужно добавить заголовок "X-Frame-Options: Deny", для запрета загрузки этой страницы во фрейме.

5-8 - зависит от используемого вами фреймворка. Если вы не используете фреймворк, тогда следует задавать вопрос "как лучше реализовать фреймворк".